# How to use multiple onSubmit functions in react-final-form?

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux-form, react-final-form

I have a form where it is possible to do 2 things with the data. I remember that in redux-form it was possible to provide a function to `handleSubmit` like so: `handleSubmit(customOnSubmit)`. What is the alternative in react-final-form?

Answer (score 0):

You'd just pass it into the `onSubmit` prop.

```
<Form onSubmit={customOnSubmit}>
  {
    ({ handleSubmit }) =>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> ...fields here... </form>
  }
</Form>
```